# Residue of product of completed Dirichlet $L$-functions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I'm trying to work out the details of Theorem 4.7.1 in Miyake's book Modular Forms, which shows how to construct modular forms from suitable pairs of Dirichlet $L$-functions. I seem to have made some minor computational error that I'm having trouble tracking down.

Let $\chi$ be an odd, primitive Dirichlet character modulo $N$. For $n \geq 1$ let
$$a_n = \sum_{d \mid n}\chi(d).$$
Then we have an $L$-function
$$L(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^s}$$
which satisfies
$$L(s) = \zeta(s)L(s,\chi),$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function and $L(s,\chi)$ is the Dirichlet $L$-function of $\chi$. Set
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\Lambda_N(s) &= (2\pi/\sqrt{N})^{-s}\Gamma(s)L(s) \\
\Lambda(s) &= (\pi)^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s) \\
\Lambda(s,\chi) &= (\pi/N)^{-s/2}\Gamma((s+1)/2)L(s,\chi)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
After some computation we find that
$$\Lambda(s)\Lambda(s,\chi) = 2\sqrt{\pi}\Lambda_N(s).$$

I need to compute the residues at the simple poles at $s = 0,1$. I've taken care of $s = 0$, but there seems to be a minor problem for the residue at $s = 1$. Now I know from the book that this residue is supposed to equal
$$-\frac{iG(\chi)B_{1,\chi}L(0,\chi)}{2\sqrt{N}},$$
where $G(\chi) = \sum_{a=1}^N\chi(a)e^{2\pi ia/N}$ is the Gauss sum of $\chi$.
I have worked this out using the functional equation for $L(s,\chi)$, but the problem is that it relates the the values of $L(s,\chi)$ to those of the function $L(1 - s,\overline{\chi})$ of the conjugate character, so I wind up with $L(0,\overline{\chi})$ instead. All of the other pieces of the desired result are there, so I must have made a mistake unless $L(0,\chi) = L(0,\overline{\chi})$. But I know how to compute these values with Bernoulli numbers, and from this one sees this cannot be the case unless $L(0,\chi)$ happens to be real.

Comment: Sure $\Lambda(s)=\Lambda(1-s)$ has two simple poles at $0,1$ of residue $1$ and $\Lambda(s,\chi)=\Lambda(1-s,\overline{\chi})$ is entire so you are right that $\Lambda(s)\Lambda(s,\chi)$ has two simple poles at $0,1$ of residue $L(0,\chi)$ and $L(0,\overline{\chi})$.

Then you can look at $f(z,\chi) =C+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{2i\pi n z} \sum_{d | n} \chi(d) $ the inverse Mellin transform of $N^{-s/2} \Lambda_N(s)$ to find $f(-1/(Nz),\chi) = G(\chi) N^{1/2} z^{-1} f(z,\overline{\chi})$

Comment: Also from $ \chi(n) = \frac{G(\chi)}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N \overline{\chi(k)} e^{2i\pi kn/N}$ and $\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi z}-1}=\frac12+\sum_l \frac{1}{z+l}$ you obtain $f(z,\chi)=-G(\chi)\sum_m\sum_l \frac{\overline{\chi(|l|)}}{Nmz+l}$ an Eisenstein of weight $1$ for $\Gamma_0(N)$ and character $\overline{\chi}$